# transfer file from mobile phone to another via bluetooth

Tags: java, java-me, bluetooth, jsr82

I've been searching high and low on this problem. Still can't find the solution.
Basically, I want to transfer an encrypted file via OBEX Push Service (bluetooth) from client (j2me) to server (j2me). In emulator, it works fine. Client able to successfully do a bluetooth discovery lookup on the server.

But, when I put the application inside my phone. It doesn't show anything at all. I guess it might be a server or client url problem.

Can anyone help me?

Here's some of my code (most probably is this that cause my problem).

(Client)

```
discoveryAgent.searchServices(null,new UUID[] { new UUID(1105) },
  (RemoteDevice) list.getRemoteDevices().elementAt(i), this);
```

(Server)

```
sn = (SessionNotifier) Connector.open(
  "btgoep://localhost:1105;name=ObexPushServer;authenticate=false;master=false;encrypt=false");
```

I tried replacing 1105 (in the server) with "00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF", but still the same result.

Comment: if this works on emulator but not on device, add which device you're using to your question. both client and server please.

Answer (score 0):

The way you use UUID is incorrect. I am surprised it even works in emulator.

You need to create UUID like this,

```
UUID uuid = new UUID("1105", true);
```

and use the same uuid in searchServices and URL. For example,

```
String url = "btgoep://localhost:" + uuid + ";name=ObexPushServer;authenticate=false;master=false;encrypt=false";
```

Comment: Hi,
Forget to mention, the UUID is what you have typed, I'm just basically converting the uuid into string for easier reference.

Sorry. Anyway, it still unable to work.